# mysterious methods in Java stacktrace

Tags: java, debugging, stack-trace

I have some doubt on analyzing the java stack trace. I am analyzing a java application and in the logs I am seeing a stacktrace. Given below  --

```
com.naseve.vdi.common.winauth.WinAuthException: Unable to set password expiry: Failed to retrieve account days to expiry: IADsUser::get_PasswordExpirationDate FAILED - ErrorCode = -2147463156
at com.naseve.vdi.broker.filters.GssapiAuthFilter.a(SourceFile:295)
at com.naseve.vdi.broker.filters.GssapiAuthFilter.a(SourceFile:241)
at net.propero.portal.filters.ProperoAuthFilter.doFilter(SourceFile:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
```

My point of concern is the part at the top. I have full access to the source code and I am 100% sure that the GssapiAuthFilter does-not have any methods named as a(). So why is the stacktrace printed like that. Also, when I am doing remote debugging using Eclipse, I am seeing similar stacktrace in the eclipse debug view. Can anyone shed some light as to the mysterious .a( methods that appear to creep out of nowhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a()` is a common method for obfuscated code. If you have been given the source it might not be obfuscated but the code you are running is.

Its best to ask the people who support the library

Answer (score 2):

The classes that are obfuscated usually have methods named that way.

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that you have access to the relevant source code. The obfuscated part is from the GSS-API implementation and all the implementations I've seen have been likewise obfuscated. Your code enters the implementation indirectly, through the class you have declared in the Java security configuration (I think it all branches out of the LoginModule configuration).